# Custom Admin Pagination links

Tags: wp-admin, pagination

I am talking about the wordpress admin area where all the posts reside.

I would like to ask if there is a way to show not only the first and the last pagination links but also the links in the middle.eg 1,2,3 .... 6,7 last page..

I am trying to manipulate `wp_list_table` class with no success.

Comment: I think this might give you a cluttered pagination view when you have many pages. I think that's the reason for current pagination design.

Comment: I think you are right..

Answer (score 0):

Currently (with WP 3.5.1) we ain't got any possibility (means: no hook or filter) to alter the output of the pagination. Everything inside the `WP_Posts_List_Table` class and its method `pagination()` and the `WP_List_Table` class method `pagination` is hard coded.

So your only chance would be to replace the `$GLOBAL` on the fly with a class that `extend`s the core `WP_Post_List_Table`.

Comment: @ArchimidisM See update